# ¿Como leer una cadena caracter por caracter?

Tags: c++, bucles

tengo el problema de introducir una cadena caracter por caracter, no encuentro cual puede ser mas optima si *getchar, getch, getche, etc*
adjunto un pedazo del codigo

```
void cadenaUna() {
  char ch;
  char cadena[1000];
  int i=0;

  do{
    ch = getche();
    cadena[i++] = ch;
  }while(ch!='\r');

  cadena[i]=='\0';
  cout << cadena[i];
}
```

cuando termina el ciclo imprime "basura", creo que mi problema es en como estoy manejando getche y el fin de linea

Comment: Todo tu código es básicamente de C. No hay nada de C++, a excepción del `cout` (por lo tanto, la etiqueta debería ser cambiada a C) ... Por último, ¿a que te refieres a cual puede ser mas óptima? ¿Será en cuestión de tiempo de ejecución o de ahorro de memoria? El término óptimo significa muchas cosas...

Comment: Adicionalmente a lo comentado por @MrDave1999... ¿En serio es necesario preocuparse por la eficiencia en este caso?

Comment: Te imprime basura porque estás haciendo una comparación y no una asignación en `cadena[i]=='\0'`, cuando debería ser `cadena[i]='\0'`. El resto de tu pregunta, ya tal.

Comment: No busques `'\r'` como final de cadena, no lo vas a encontrar. Busca `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tengo el problema de introducir una cadena carácter por carácter, no encuentro cual puede ser mas optima.

Eso no es un problema, o al menos no es el problema que crees.

---

Para empezar, tienes un problema semántico: "*Óptimo*" es un [superlativo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superlativo), no se puede ser más óptimo ni menos óptimo.

> #### [óptimo, ma](https://dle.rae.es/?w=%C3%B3ptimo)
>
> *Del lat. optĭmus*.
>
> 1. adj. Sumamente bueno, **que no puede ser mejor**.

Seguidamente, tienes un problema conceptual. No debes ponerte a buscar la solución óptima para un código genérico si no buscar optimizar código concreto cuando es necesario (ni antes ni después).

El [Principio de Pareto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_Pareto) emerge en el código de la siguiente manera: "*El 80% del código se ejecuta el 20% del tiempo*", preocuparse por optimizar partes no críticas del código es una pérdida de tiempo, esa pérdida de tiempo se conoce como "*optimización prematura*" ([*early/premature optimization*](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) en inglés).

Finalmente, si tienes dudas sobre el rendimiento de una función, lo primero es buscar información ([RTFM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)):

#### [`std::getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar).

Esta función lee un carácter de la consola de entrada, devuelve un entero (`int`) que deberá ser convertido a carácter (`char`). Es una función del lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) adaptada a C++; no debería usarse salvo que sea absolutamente necesario (casi nunca lo es), en su lugar usa `std::cin.get(carácter)`.

#### [`std::getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc).

Las funciones `getch` y `getche` no existen, supongo que te refieres a `std::getc`. Lee un carácter del flujo de datos proveído, devuelve un entero (`int`) que deberá ser convertido a carácter (`char`). Es una función del lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) adaptada a C++; no debería usarse salvo que sea absolutamente necesario (casi nunca lo es), en su lugar usa `std::cin.get(carácter)`.

> Cuando termina el ciclo imprime "basura", creo que mi problema es en como estoy manejando getche y el fin de línea.

No, tu problema es que vas leyendo carácter a carácter y guardando en `cadena` desde la posición cero hasta donde llegues, pero cuando muestras por pantalla, muestras el carácter (un único carácter) después del último leído:

```
do{
  ch = getche();
  cadena[i++] = ch;
//       ^^^ <--- Lee en la posición i y avanza una posición.
}while(ch!='\r');

// …

cout << cadena[i];
//             ^ <--- Lo último que leíste fue i - 1
```

Lo que seguramente querías hacer es esto:

```
cout << cadena;
```

Pero lo que deberías estar haciendo es:

```
void cadenaUna() {
    // No uses formaciones, usa objetos cadena de carácter.
    std::string cadena;

    char ch;
    do {
        std::cin.get(ch);
        cadena.push_back(ch);
    // El salto de línea es '\n', no '\r'.
    } while (ch!='\n');

    std::cout << cadena;
}
```

O mejor aún, no reinventes la rueda. Puedes leer una línea con una sola instrucción:

```
std::string cadena;
std::getline(std::cin, cadena);
std::cout << cadena;
```